# slim template within template crashing in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, slim-lang

I'm using slim with Sinatra and have a strange problem. Inside one slim template I am trying to render another slim like so:

```
p
  == slim :search_form
```

This works perfectly in another template, but for some reason I get the following exception:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Oct/2014 20:00:47] "GET /__sinatra__/500.png HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.0010
NoMethodError - undefined method `join' for #<String:0x007f9dc2c39f30>:
        views/results.slim:45:in `block in singleton class'
        views/results.slim:-1:in `instance_eval'
        views/results.slim:-1:in `singleton class'
        views/results.slim:-3:in `__tilt_70157989336980'
        /Users/brendan/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/template.rb:170:in `call'
        /Users/brendan/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/template.rb:170:in `evaluate'
        /Users/brendan/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/template.rb:103:in `render'
        /Users/brendan/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:814:in `render'
        /Users/brendan/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:742:in `slim'
        app.rb:80:in `block in <class:Website>'
        /Users/brendan/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1603:in `call
```

Comment: Has this issue been resolved?